# IntelliJ: "java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host <xx.x.x.xx>"

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to import the maven project in the IntelliJ, however maven is not able to resolve the dependecies and getting below error:

```
"java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 10.10.10.10; nested exception is:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

[intelliJScreenshotOfError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAVjx.png)

Previously it was working fine perfectly, but due to some reason I deleted the .idea folder from the project and this issue take place.

I tried below thing till now

- re-install the IntelliJ many times
- Clone the project again on fresh directory and reimported in intelliJ
- perform repair IDE in IntelliJ
- reload all from disk in IntelliJ
- Invalidate Cache

but nothing worked for me

Any lead how to resolve this issue now ?

Comment: you deleted project configuration for Intellij. You need to check your Maven configuration in IntelliJ and found reason why you try to connect to host: 10.10.10.10. Share .pom file (if you can) and mvn version

Comment: - Shared pom.xml screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAVjx.png

- maven version: Apache Maven 3.9.4

- java version: openjdk version "17.0.8.1" 2023-08-24 LTS

Comment: You need to add your .pom to maven project.

Comment: This might be due to IDEA failing to establish a connection to the Maven process it runs to process and import your Project. Is often happens because of firewalls/antiviruses/etc. You may find this article useful: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360014262940

Answer (score 0):

1. Close the IntelliJ
2. Open environment variables
3. Delete the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS from user variables / system variables
4. Start the IntelliJ
5. Import the maven project.
6. And error is gone.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).